# BASH If service runtime statement

Tags: bash

I'm missing the mark on this and I'm just not getting why.  I writing a troubleshooter for a custom logstash (But could be any service) deployment we are doing.

The intent:
Check to see if the service has been running longer than 1 minute if has then
Report good then move on to other checks I'm writing
-If not running more than 1-minute wait until 60 seconds on service time and then do checks.
-If service uptime starts over or service is in failed status post error.

```
SERVICE=logstash
SERVICE_START_TIME=`systemctl status $SERVICE | awk '/Active: active/{print $6" "$7}'`
SERVICE_UP_TIME=$(($(date +%s) - $(date -d "$SERVICE_START_TIME" +%s)))


if systemctl is-active logstash --quiet = active && $SERVICE_UP_TIME > 60s; then
 echo "Logstash is Operating as expected"
elif systemctl is-active logstash = active; then
 echo "Waiting on Logstash to run more than 1 minutes"
wait 60s
else
 echo "Service is NOT Running"
fi
```

I can get $SERVICE_UP_TIME to return a number but I can't make it validate against 60 seconds (60s).

Thoughts, I feel I'm doing this the hard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `=` argument to `systemctl`. With the `--quiet` option it just sets its exit status, there's nothing to compare with `active`.

To compare numbers, you need to use `[ expression ]`. You also shouldn't have `s` after `60`, and you have to use the `-gt` option; `>` is output redirection.

```
if systemctl is-active logstash --quiet && [ "$SERVICE_UP_TIME" -gt 60 ]; then
    echo "Logstash is Operating as expected"
elif systemctl is-active logstash --quiet; then
    echo "Waiting on Logstash to run more than 1 minutes"
    sleep 60
else
    echo "Service is NOT Running"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you.  Not fully appreciate Bash as much...

Why is there no ability for is-active to validate?  Seems off to me but validated what you wrote.  Thank you again!

Comment: `is-active` doesn't produce output, it sets its exit status, which is what `if` checks.